# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'posts.urls'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm starting with Django by seeing a tutorial, when I start editing urls.py, I start giving these errors:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\salva\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "c:\users\salva\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Salva\mydjangoblog\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Salva\mydjangoblog\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\Salva\mydjangoblog\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = self._run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\Salva\mydjangoblog\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Salva\mydjangoblog\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\Salva\mydjangoblog\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Salva\mydjangoblog\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\Salva\mydjangoblog\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 407, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\Salva\mydjangoblog\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Salva\mydjangoblog\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Salva\mydjangoblog\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Salva\mydjangoblog\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 581, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "c:\users\salva\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Salva\mydjangoblog\mydjangoblog\mydjangoblog\urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path(r'^',include('posts.urls'))
  File "C:\Users\Salva\mydjangoblog\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "c:\users\salva\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'posts.urls'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Salva\mydjangoblog\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Salva\mydjangoblog\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Salva\mydjangoblog\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Salva\mydjangoblog\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Salva\mydjangoblog\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Salva\mydjangoblog\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\Salva\mydjangoblog\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Salva\mydjangoblog\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 599, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Salva\mydjangoblog\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 584, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "C:\Users\Salva\mydjangoblog\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 299, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "C:\Users\Salva\mydjangoblog\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 305, in run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "C:\Users\Salva\mydjangoblog\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 345, in tick
    for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "C:\Users\Salva\mydjangoblog\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 361, in snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():
  File "C:\Users\Salva\mydjangoblog\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 260, in watched_files
    yield from iter_all_python_module_files()
  File "C:\Users\Salva\mydjangoblog\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 105, in iter_all_python_module_files
    return iter_modules_and_files(modules, frozenset(_error_files))
  File "C:\Users\Salva\mydjangoblog\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 141, in iter_modules_and_files
    resolved_path = path.resolve(strict=True).absolute()
  File "c:\users\salva\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\pathlib.py", line 1174, in resolve
    s = self._flavour.resolve(self, strict=strict)
  File "c:\users\salva\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\pathlib.py", line 200, in resolve
    return self._ext_to_normal(_getfinalpathname(s))
OSError: [WinError 123] La sintassi del nome del file, della directory o del volume non è corretta: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
```

Below are the various source codes that may serve:

Principal urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'^',include('posts.urls'))
]
```

urls.py of post(folder):

```
from django.urls import path
from my_app import views as post_views

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^',posts_views.lista_post, name="lista")
    path(r'^',posts_views.post_singolo, name="singolo")
    path(r'^',posts_views.contatti, name="contatti")
]
```

Views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def lista_post(request):
    return render(request,"Lista_post.html")

def post_singolo():
    return render(request,"post_singolo.html")

def contatti():
    return render(request,"Contatti.html")
```

Please help! 
I put the urls.py in the migration folder of post folder

First urls.py:
C:\Users\Salva\mydjangoblog\mydjangoblog\mydjangoblog

Second urls.py:
C:\Users\Salva\mydjangoblog\mydjangoblog\posts\migrations

I'm using Django 3.0.4

Comment: do you have posts app in django installed apps ?

Comment: Note, your post.urls is broken: no commas in the urlpatterns list. And why did you put this file into `migrations` folder? This is not the right place.

Answer (score 0):

urls.py should not be in the migration folder, but on `your_app/urls.py`

The migration folder contains all the necessary files needed to create the database schema (creation and modifications).

```
your_project/
   - settings.py
   - urls.py # project URLs
   - wsgi.py
your_app/
   - migrations/
   - models.py
   - views.py
   - urls.py  # app URLs
manage.py
```

Comment: With `your_app` I mean you application name. I edited my answer adding more details.

Comment: Thanks, i fixed it. But now i have another problem. See my next post..